# Can't upload war file through tomcat manager dashboard with VPN

Tags: configuration, centos7, tomcat

I have configured server and deployed war file earlier. All of those I did in **Digital Ocean**'s **CentOS** server. Now I need to configure  **CentOS** server In Local Data Center. I have configured **Tomcat** as usual way. Tomcat is running. I can access tomcat manager dashboard. Problem is when I am trying to deploy war file I am getting error. This is the dashboard of tomcat manager.

[image]

But when I hit deploy I am getting connection error.

[image]

> Note that, I had to access provided IP address with VPN. Because it
>   was a requirement to access this IP with VPN.

As I am getting error in 80 port I changed tomcat port to 8080. 
Then I traced server and Get this error

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
       at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
       at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:440)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:775)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:721)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
```

Also getting this error

```
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.396 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.396 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.426 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.426 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.426 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Feb-2019 17:18:59.427 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: This is your first deployment in the new data center? Your HTTP connector is running on port 80 and Tomcat was started as root? Nothing else is running on this port (e.g. Apache)?

Comment: @Freddy ,   Yes this is first time in this data center. Yes tomcat is started as root. But I don't know how to check Other programs are running on port 80. Can you please help me ?

Comment: Run `netstat -tlpn | grep ':80'` as root. The output shows the running PID and program if there is something running.

Comment: @Freddy I have changed port to 8080. When I use `netstat -tlpn | grep ':8080' ` I am getting this `tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      106872/java`

Comment: @Freddy Now I am getting error `java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)` . What an I do now :( ?

Comment: I have changed tomcat port 80 to 8080 then started tomcat again. After all of this I am getting `java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)` What should I do now ?

Comment: After changing port to 8080.

Comment: Start over. Stop tomcat (if running). Make sure there are no java processes running (`ps aux|grep java`). Kill running java processes (`kill -9 PID`). Run netstat and make sure nothing is listening on the port. Open second terminal and run `tail -f` on your catalina.*log. Delete your webapp inside the "webapps" folder. _Then_ start tomcat. Check again with netstat and watch the output of your logfile. _Then_ deploy your webapp (still watching the logfile).

Comment: @Freddy I have no `webapp` folder inside `webapps` folder. And can you please write command step by step ?

Comment: I have no `webapp` folder inside `webapps`

Comment: @Freddy I updated my question. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

I was deploying someother `.war` file in tomcat 8.
To successfully deploy change the max upload and max request.
Open tomcat installation directory then edit  `Tomcat 8.0/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml` in a text editor
and find the lines with the text: `<max-file-size>` and `<max-request-size>`.
Increase its value.
Ex:

```
<max-file-size>100428800</max-file-size>
<max-request-size>100428800</max-request-size>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: great ! you saved my day :)